Excel vba Nested Forms Listbox missing data
I'm using multiple forms in excel vba and each form for itself works nicely.
I've created frmMainMenu to call these forms and whenever I call some of them, listboxes in them are not filled with data.
Codes for fill data in listboxes are written in Modules. Each form has it's own Module where I wrote lot of codes.
Does anyone have idea what's wrong? Is there some rule?
Since I pull data via ADODB connection, I've done debugging of rs! and all data is present, but listbox keeps empty.
Of course, whenever I run form directly, I have data in listboxes. The same is happening with everything connected to the Modules.
Here is part of the code relevant for call of the another forms.
Private Sub TreeView1_DblClick()
    Dim selectedNode As MSComctlLib.Node
    Dim formName As String
    
    ' Get the selected node
    Set selectedNode = Me.TreeView1.selectedItem
    
    ' Check if the selected node is a child node and has a form association
    If ChildNodeFormAssociation.exists(selectedNode.key) Then
        formName = ChildNodeFormAssociation(selectedNode.key)
        ' Open the corresponding form (assuming form names are UserForms in Excel)
        OpenUserFormByName formName
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OpenUserFormByName(formName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim frm As Object
    Set frm = VBA.UserForms.Add(formName)
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Failed to open form: " & formName, vbExclamation
    Else
        ' Calculate the position to open formName adjacent to frmMainMenu
        Dim frmMainMenuLeft As Long
        Dim frmMainMenuTop As Long
        
        ' Adjust these values according to your form's size
        frmMainMenuLeft = Me.Left
        frmMainMenuTop = Me.Top
        
        ' Position formName adjacent to frmMainMenu
        frm.StartUpPosition = 0 ' Manual
        
        ' Ensure no space between frmMainMenu and formName
        frm.Left = frmMainMenuLeft + Me.Width
        frm.Top = frmMainMenuTop
        
        ' Show the form
        frm.Show
        
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

I've found out issue is how I call these other forms.
For example, here I used VBA.UserForms.Add(formName) which is creating dynamically these forms.
But I don't know how to properly write this code to call form which I already have.
I've tried to use:
VBA.UserForms(formName) and UserForms(formName) but it didn't work properly, of course, because of type mismatch.

How to be helped if your code cannot be seen? At least, show the mentioned list boxes loading. How is it done? Is this proces the object of an initial form event (Initialize, Activate etc.)? Where from the necessary data is taken? And how? Do you use arrays and List list box property? Iterations on sheet ranges and AddItem? If not, how do you add items to them? Since, this looks to be your real problem...

@FaneDuru I've updated it. How does Listbox itself work doesn't matter, because it works 100% fine.
I've tested by simply creating button in frmMainMenu with exactnameoftheform.Show and it worked normally.

I am afraid I cannot get you... Are you able to show these forms? As you formulated the question I understand you can, but your single problem is the fact that their list boxes are empty. Did I miss anything? And I said "show the mentioned list boxes loading (code)"... Did you do that and I am missing it? Should I understand that your problem is not related at all to the list box loading, as you wrote in the question title? Is it a matter of not being able to show the forms?

I am able to see form, but not the data inside objects in the form when form is loaded first time from frmMainMenu. If I load form 2nd time, it loads data. That's due to VBA.UserForms.Add(formName)
I want to avoid that issue and that my data in form is loaded when I first time load form via frmMainMenu. I hope I've explained it better.
Regarding listboxes loading code - it is not important, it works just fine. Issue is in dynamically calling of forms from frmMainMenu.

Not sure I am able to understand what you say, no offence... I cannot know what frmMainMenu is. It probably should be something secret... You firstly say "I am able to see form, but not the data inside objects in the form when form is loaded first time from frmMainMenu". Then "my data in form is loaded when I first time load form via frmMainMenu"... Never mind, VBA.UserForms.Add(formName).Show works as it should only first time after adding it as VBComponent and use .Designer to add controls.

To show it after that, having the added controls and their events, by its name string you should use something as: Dim myForm As Object Set myForm = CallByName(UserForms, "Add", VbMethod, formName) myForm.Show.
